# Angular check box filters the products not working

Tags: angular

Hello I am trying to create an ecommerce page on angular where the products are shown with the checkbox option to filter the products. However I am not able to make the checkbox filter work. Please help.

Here is my code -

```
<div class="brand-select">
<div class="brand-name">Select Color</div>
<form>
    <div class="form-check brand-checkbox" *ngFor="let col of colors;let index = index">
        <input class="form-check-input" 
             type="checkbox" 
             value="{{col.id}}" 
             id="{{col.id}}" 
             name="checkbox" 
             [(ngModel)]="col.selected"
             (ngModelChange)="filterProducts()">

          <label class="form-check-label" for="{{col.id}}">
            {{col.productColor}}
          </label>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let prod of productListShow">
    <div *ngFor="let product of prod.product">
        <h5 class="product-inner-title">{{product.productName}}</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my component `.ts` file -

```
public colors: any[] = [
{
  id: 1,
  productColor: "Black",
  selected: false,
},
{
  id: 2,
  productColor: "Green",
  selected: false,
}
]
constructor(private productservice: ProductService) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.productList = this.productservice.getProducts();
 this.productListShow = this.productList; 
}

  public filterProducts(): void {
  const filteredProductArray = new Array<any>();
  const activeColors = this.colors.filter(c => c.selected).map(c => c.productColor);
  this.productList.forEach(prod => {
      const filteredSubProducts = prod.product.filter(p => activeColors.includes(p.productColor));
       if(filteredSubProducts.length > 0){
           const clonedProduct = Object.assign({}, prod);
           clonedProduct.product = filteredSubProducts;
           filteredProductArray.push(clonedProduct);
       }
  });
  this.productListShow = filteredProductArray;
  console.log(this.productListShow);
}
```

I am getting the data for my products from a service `ProductService` here is the data for the products -

```
import { Products } from './products';
export const PRODUCTS: Products[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        productCat:'Jeans',
        product: [
            {
                productId: '1',
                productName: 'Trendy Black',
                productColor: 'Black',
            },
            {
                productId: '2',
                productName: 'Trendy Green',
                productColor: 'Green',
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

Please help. In my console log it is giving me an empty array.
[image: My console Log no errors but the array is empty]

UPDATE -

In my logic I have corrected my mistake to map(c => c.productColor)

Now when I check the checkbox it filters all the results from every `productCat`, as I am loading the products based on the `productCat` for example for `productCat` = Jeans only jeans products will show.

Here is my file  -

```
import { Products } from './products';
export const PRODUCTS: Products[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        productCat:'Jeans',
        product: [
            {
                productId: '1',
                productName: 'Trendy Jeans',
                productColor: 'Green',
            },
            {
                productId: '2',
                productName: 'Black tapered Jeans',
                productColor: 'Black',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        productCat:'Shirts',
        product: [
            {
                productId: '1',
                productName: 'Trendy Shirts',
                productColor: 'Green',
            },
            {
                productId: '2',
                productName: 'Black Shirts',
                productColor: 'Black',
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

So When I check green color, it filters all the green color data, i.e shows the green products both from `productCat` Jeans and Shirts. I only want to show the green color products for jeans if I am showing only jeans data. Please help.

Comment: Please include the error log being shown in browser

Comment: Hi @NitishkumarSingh, I have updated my question, no errors but I am getting an empty array

Comment: You should stop using `any`. By doing that, you 're telling TypeScript that it shouldn't check for your mistakes. But you're doing mistakes, like for example `.map(c => c.color)`, which transform each color into undefined, since colors don't have any `color` property.

Comment: Hi @JBNizet Thanks, It was my mistake, It changed c.color to c.productColor. The products are filtering but it is filtering from all the list. I will update my answer to explain it better

Comment: HI @JBNizet I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see `color` in objects of `colors` array, it should be `c.productColor` in map as:

```
public filterProducts(): void {
      ...
      const activeColors = this.colors.filter(c => c.selected).map(c => c.productColor);
      ...
}
```

UPDATE 1:

```
productCategory: string;

ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params .subscribe(params => { 
        if (params.type) {
            this.productCategory = params.type;
        }
        ...
    });
}

public filterProducts(): void {
    let filteredProductArray;
    const activeColors = this.colors.filter(c => c.selected).map(c => c.productColor);
    let productData = this.productList.find(product => product.productCat == this.productCategory);
    this.productListShow = [];
    if(productData) {
        let filteredProductData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(productData))
        let products = productData.product;
        filteredProductData.product = products.filter(product => activeColors.includes(product.productColor));
        this.productListShow.push(filteredProductData);
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, It is giving me error for the below line - `let filteredProductArray = products.filter(product => activeColors.includes(productColor));` in filter as `does not exist as type products` and in includes(productColor) for productColor cannot find name productColor

Comment: @Akshay updated answer I missed `product.` Also not that while calling `filterProducts` you will have to pass `category name`

Comment: Hi @Anshuman, thanks for the update. In `filterProducts` I am passing like this `(ngModelChange)="filterProducts(prod.productCat)` in checkbox input, is it a correct way, also folr `filter` I am still getting the error `does not exist as type products`. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: hi @Anshuman, thanks I am not getting any errors, still confused how to pass category name `(ngModelChange)="filterProducts()"` for `productCat`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172823/discussion-between-anshuman-jaiswal-and-akshay).